# Reveal Divs Content On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not really sure how to word what I'm looking for in search engine terms, so what I'm trying to do is:

I want to have a division, or two if that's what it takes, in the center of the page that when clicked seperates.  Top portion slides up, bottom portion slides down and it reveals the website content in the middle.

---

[image: click]

---

[image: slide]

---

I'm not exactly sure how word my search for something that does that properly.  I've seen a few websites that have variations of this.  Only ones that open left/right though.  I'm sure this is difficult, but any help towards achieving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance, Bc.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: so like an opening window type thing?

Comment: Yeah, basically.  With the help of some other stack overflow users a while back, I've been toying around with this code, but I'm not the most advanced when it comes to jquery.  I wish I could be more helpful in explaining what I'm trying to do, but I'm having trouble wording it myself.

In short:  An onclick division that splits in the middle; top goes up, bottom goes down; and it reveals all of the websites content in the middle where it splits.

http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/QchfJ/

Comment: try jQuery UI Accordion widget. http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking into right now.  I just don't think I have enough jquery knowledge to make it adapt the way I'm hoping to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need : http://jsfiddle.net/WQCav/

HTML :

```
<div id="hider1" style="position:absolute;background-color:black;width:100%;height:50%;" onclick="displayWebsite();" ></div>
<div id="hider2" style="background-color:black;width:100%;height:50%;position:absolute;top:50%;" onclick="displayWebsite();" ></div>
HI
```

JS :

```
var up,down;
function displayWebsite()
{
    if(typeof up!=="undefined")return;
    up=setInterval(goUp,20);
    down=setInterval(goDown,20);
}
function goUp(x)
{
    var h1=document.getElementById("hider1");
    if(h1.offsetHeight<=80)
    {
        clearInterval(up);
        return;
    }
    h1.style.height=parseInt(h1.style.height)-1+"%";
}
function goDown(x)
{
    var h2=document.getElementById("hider2");
    if(h2.offsetHeight<=80)
    {
        clearInterval(down);
        return;
    }
    h2.style.top=parseInt(h2.style.top)+1+"%";
    h2.style.height=parseInt(h2.style.height)-1+"%";
}
```

CSS :

```
html,body
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Very close!  Thank you so much for doing that.  I got it to where it stops based on a %, but is there anyway to tell it to stop 80px from the stop instead of 10%, same for bottom?
http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/7QkZv/6/
Thanks again, Bc.

Comment: Ah, also.  Just noticed that when you click the div again after it stops 10% from top or bottom that it does the function again and starts to scroll infinitely.  Anyway to tell it that after one click, don't do anything?

Comment: I edited the code! PS:If there is any question about the code just ask.

Comment: Looks awesome, man.  Very awesome.  The only thing I could think that would improve it is if it opened up a bit smoother.  I know it's different code, but I'm not sure if it might help to achieve a smoother transition.  This is one of the versions I had help with a while back and it's transition is so smooth:  http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/QchfJ/  I'm not guessing there's any way to achieve that on such a large scale like the one you've made for me?  Thanks again for all of the help.  I hope I don't sound like an elitist, just curious if it's possible.  Bc.

Comment: Go here http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/timing-function/ scroll a little bit and you will see 6 different transition. I think that what you want is ease-in-out but if not tell me.

Comment: Once you chose the transition, tell me and I'll (re)modify the code.

Comment: Finally, I can't. I searched a lot and it's very complicated with your case (to stop at 80px by making the setinterval changing in %). You can try to post a question about the transition in js. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for everything man.  After playing around with it for awhile, I think I like the version you did where it goes completely off the screen.  It's just a little choppy and I can't seem to smooth out the kinks in it.  I came across this, and while the top completely hides itself, the bottom just scrolls down.  http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/ZCh9x/26/  I had tried wrapping everything in a container with overflow:hidden, but didn't get it working.  I really like how smooth the transition is though.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on how to do it yet, as I'm still fairly new to using stackoverflow, but would you mind opening a chat with me?  No worries if not.  Thanks, Bc.

Comment: Ok, but when we are connected at the same time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11661/discussion-between-itsbc-and-mageek)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JQuery, you can simply use [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) on the target div.

**Edit**

Actually, in this case I think *slideToggle* is what you're looking for:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".button").click(function() {
            $("#content).slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<div class='button'>Top Panel</div>
<div id='content'>Content</div>
<div>Bottom Panel</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I've been toying around with one as well; http://jsfiddle.net/itsbc/QchfJ/ , but I'm not sure where to begin to make it open up the way I'm wanting.  I basically want the division to split in half.  Imagine the black div that says 'test' being centered vertically and horizontally on the screen, then the black opening up to the top of the screen, blue opening up to the bottom, and the content being revealed in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished fixing this issue.  I did not want the div to go over the material below it but shift it down.  This will get the division splitting in half feel that you want - you will need something below the sliding div(like another div, or a div that has some invisible height to it and height on Auto in CSS to make it work for your main wrap.

Here is what I did:

My CSS:

```
.slide {
    height:200px;
    background-color: white;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0 3px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.24);

}




#show_div {
    margin-left: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    font-size: 20px;


}
```

This was to make it look pretty.  Below is more of the function:

```
.show_hide {
    display:none;
```

Coding:  In the header I put the JQ function:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slide").hide();
        $(".show").show();

    $('.show').click(function(){
    $(".slide").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

​

Then in the div itself don't forget to place the actual good stuff that will style your div to perform the way you like:

```
<a id="show_div" href="#" class="show">Browse Styles</a>


    <div class="slide">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus fermentum, nibh at iaculis ultrices, mi eros tincidunt enim, vitae vehicula lectus odio a ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce id nisl sit amet diam iaculis pulvinar. Sed ultrices ullamcorper ornare. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis mi arcu, porta ut elementum et, ullamcorper sed eros. In euismod tellus sed ipsum adipiscing suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ac magna dui. Aenean nec leo libero. Pellentesque lacinia dolor a dui lacinia consectetur. Mauris euismod porta magna, non dignissim orci adipiscing malesuada. Phasellus nunc sapien, consectetur nec vestibulum ac, euismod a ipsum.

    </div>
​
```

The main back draw on this is that you will need to place one instance of the Jscript for each div that you want to use this for, otherwise they will all activate at the same time.  You can  place the button(or link) anywhere on the page.  I have a couple of them side by side and when clicked they split the page from the same location.

If you need multiple of these don't forget to give the divs unique ids and to change their name in the Jscript to make the magic happen.

HERE IS A JFIDDLE EXAMPLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/vH3cK/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for doing this.  I tried putting it into a fiddle, but couldn't seem to get the effect to work.  Did you happen to do it in fiddle and if so, would you mind if I took a look at it?  Thanks again, Bc.

Comment: Made some changes - check out the JFIDDLE for clarification. Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  A while back when playing with some code that I had help with, I was able to achieve a similar effect to what you're showing in the fiddle.  This code that Mageek posted is identical to the effect I'm trying to achieve; I just transitioned a little bit smoother.  I'm gonna reply to his answer as well and see if he knows of any way to achieve that, but if not I think that it will work just fine for what I'm going for.  Thanks again, Bc.

Answer (score 0):

The first "div" should be composed of two different divs, one for the top part and another for the bottom. Your page content should be styled "display:none" at first. When the user clicks on the first div, show the page content using "$(selector).slideDown(500)". Would have to test it, but I think it should work like a charm.
You could try using .show(), .toggle() and different ammounts of time (in miliseconds) to see what fits best.

Comment: Is there a way to make it to where onclick "$(#topdiv).SlideUp(500)" and also from the same click have it to where "$(#bottomdiv).SlideDown(500)".  I'd also need it to slide from the center of the page to the top/bottom based on percentages.  The idea is so that no matter what the resolution, it always goes to the very top and very bottom of the visible page.  Thanks for your response, Bc.

Comment: The resolution problem is just css. It depends on the way you set the size of the content. I'm not sure about the first question though.. try using show on the inner content and not on the top and bottom divs.

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery .animate() function might be something to look into as well -- it uses CSS, which is generally better practice.